# MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT is not working in Android 7

Tags: android

I want to restrict user for `capturing video` when `limit` reaches to 15Mb but on android 7 devices **MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT** is not working.Is there any alternative to do so or there are some changes for the same requirement

```
Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // set the video image quality to high
        takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
        //takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT,30); //30 sec
        takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, 15728640L); //15*1024*1024=15MiB(15728640L)//50*1024*1024=50MiB(52428800L)
        startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, RESULT_CAPTURE_VIDEO);`
```

Comment: try with `intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 10);` it will restrict at a time, works on my galaxy s7 edge api 24, determine howmuch time 15MB's duration and change duration as per that..

Comment: Actually, can't restrict user at a particular time need to restrict to size.

Answer (score 3):

> on android 7 devices MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT is not working

This has nothing to do with the OS or its version. You are asking a third-party camera app to record a video and limit the size. It is up to the implementers of that camera app to honor your request. There is no requirement for any camera app to honor your request, on any version of Android. Consider this limit to be a hint, not a demand.

> Is there any alternative to do so

Write your own video-recording camera logic, either using `MediaRecorder` directly or perhaps through a wrapper library (e.g., CameraKit-Android).

Comment: As the same code snippet works well for OS version before 7 that's the reason I thought maybe it's due to the version 7

Comment: @shekharshrivastava: "As the same code snippet works well for OS version before 7" -- no, it works with the *particular camera apps* that you happened to have tested on Android 6.0 and lower. There are ~2 billion Android devices, spread across ~10,000 device models from hundreds of manufacturers. There are hundreds of built-in camera apps, and hundreds more available for download from the Play Store and other app distribution channels. Many will honor `EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT`, but none have to, and not all will honor it.